# Native Dll Call with CStringArray

Tags: c++, string, dll, native, cstring

Consider the following code (Which works!):

```
int SetInputFile( const CString& fileName );

int SetInputFile(System::String^ fileName)
{
        const char* str = (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(fileName);
        return m_Native->SetInputFile(str); 
}
```

How do I handle/convert a case with this input?

```
int SetInputFiles( const CStringArray& fileNames );
```

Comment: You cannot call method with `CStringArray` parameter from C#. C# has no idea what is `CStringArray`. Redesign native method to make it accessible from C#.

Comment: Alex Farber - Like change to Const CString&[] with the Length in addition ?

Comment: The same error - `CString` will not work. C# can handle only plain types (like int, char), plain C-style strings (like char*, wchar_t*), arrays and structures containing these types. Don't try to use MFC types in interop code.

Comment: `int SetInputFiles(wchar_t** strings, int size)` is OK for native interop function. IntPtr structure and Marshal class contain all required stuff to provide an input for this function.

Comment: I asked because the use of CString& as a single object worked using the Marshal conversion...

Comment: It is not a `CString&` it's `const CString&` which is an LPCSTR or LPCWSTR depending on your compiler settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Alex Farber** and **Nostromoo**
After searching the web - I was unable to find and such conversion. There for I had the interface changed to receive a list of strings in a const CString& with a seperator character. Naturally your suggestions are as well good and valid solutions.